# What does (*(QUEUE **) &((*(q))[0])) mean in libuv, or How does the queue work?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, queue, libuv

I am just getting into void pointers and double pointers in C and such to try and make things dynamic. Then I came across [this](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/e4087dedf837f415056a45a838f639a3d9dc3ced/src/queue.h#L21-L25) which looks as follows:

```
typedef void *QUEUE[2];

#define QUEUE_NEXT(q)       (*(QUEUE **) &((*(q))[0]))
#define QUEUE_PREV(q)       (*(QUEUE **) &((*(q))[1]))
```

There are too many pointers, parens, and references going on for my eyes. Wondering if someone could explain:

- what that section `(*(QUEUE **) &((*(q))` is doing, and
- how this queue can only have two items.

How does this work?  Specifically, they have this:

```
#define QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL(h, q)                             \
  do {                                                      \
    QUEUE_NEXT(q) = (h);                                    \
    QUEUE_PREV(q) = QUEUE_PREV(h);                          \
    QUEUE_PREV_NEXT(q) = (q);                               \
    QUEUE_PREV(h) = (q);                                    \
  }                                                         \
  while (0)
```

How does that `QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL` work?

Or for example, I'd also be interested to know what is going on with this:

```
#define QUEUE_INIT(q)                                                         \
  do {                                                                        \
    QUEUE_NEXT(q) = (q);                                                      \
    QUEUE_PREV(q) = (q);                                                      \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

...

QUEUE_INIT(&loop->wq);
QUEUE_INIT(&loop->idle_handles);
QUEUE_INIT(&loop->async_handles);
QUEUE_INIT(&loop->check_handles);
QUEUE_INIT(&loop->prepare_handles);
QUEUE_INIT(&loop->handle_queue);
```

In the end, they all use `QUEUE_NEXT` and `QUEUE_PREV` internally, doing some sort of magic.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/5657156), which should help a bit.  Basically any structure in the queue must contain a `QUEUE` element which is used to link the elements together in a circular doubly-linked chain.  The `QUEUE_DATA` macro is used to access the original structure from a pointer to its `QUEUE` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interface to a circular linked list. When you resolve the first macro usage you get:

- `QUEUE_NEXT(&loop->wq)` ->
- `*(QUEUE **) &((*( &loop->wq ))[0])` ->
- `*(QUEUE **) &(( loop->wq )[0])` ->
- `*(QUEUE **) &( loop->wq[0] )` ->
- `*(QUEUE **) &loop->wq[0]`

which effectively is the same as `(QUEUE *)( loop->wq[0] )` or just `loop->wq[0]`

This of course works only if `wq` is of type `QUEUE` which is nothing but an array of two void pointers. The author resorted to `void*` because afaik it's impossible in C to typedef an array of pointers to itself.

And `QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL` btw is the code to splice two lists. The interesting aspect of this interface is, how do you get to the content of each element? Take a look at the definition of `QUEUE_DATA`

```
#define QUEUE_DATA(ptr, type, field)                                          \
  ((type *) ((char *) (ptr) - ((long) &((type *) 0)->field)))
```

and it's usage

```
struct user_s {
  int age;
  char* name;

  QUEUE node;
};
user = QUEUE_DATA(q, struct user_s, node);
```

This resolves to

- `QUEUE_DATA(q, struct user_s, node)` ->
- `(struct user_s*) ((char *) (q) - ((long) &((struct user_s*) 0)->node))`

which effectively returns an address to the containing struct by subtracting the offset of its `QUEUE` member, so the value of `q` is adjusted to the address of the struct (here `user_s`) it is pointing into.